# How can I count the answers that have the same values?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
--Table Answer--
Id     Question_id  Attendee_id  Answer
100    qst1          001         Name1
101    qst2          001         Name1
102    qst3          002         Name2
```

I would like to know how I can count the answers that have the same values?

Answer (score 2):

A [standard SQL aggregate](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

```
SELECT Answer, COUNT(*) FROM MyTable GROUP BY Answer
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select Answer, Count(*) FROM answer GROUP BY Answer
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT answer,COUNT(*) FROM table
GROUP BY answer
```

Answer (score 1):

For every question?

```
SELECT
    Question_id,
    Answer,
    COUNT(1) qty
GROUP BY
    Question_id, Answer
```

Exclude `Question_id` from `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` if you want the total counts, not partitioned by question, although I assume that figure would be less useful.

Comment: Note that COUNT(1) being "better" is a myth: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1221649/27535. And wrong syntax too...

Comment: @gbn: sure, it's just an old habit. it's not worse either, for the very same reasons :)